# x, y = x.float().to(device), y.float().to(device)AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'float'

Tags: python, pytorch, attributeerror

```
for epoch in range(intial_epoch, nb_epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_ndx, (x,y) in enumerate(train_loader):
       
        x, y = x.float().to(device), y.float().to(device)
        pred = model(x)
        loss = criterion(pred, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

while training giving this problem.

I tried to convert str to float but failed by normal float function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please **[edit]** your question to improve it. Like telling us the language you're writing that code in (add it as a tag).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `x` and `y` are numbers in string format (or else the conversion will give error), change `x.float()` and `y.float()` to `float(x)` and `float(y)`.

Comment: tried but giving error that unable to convert it into float

Comment: What are the data inside `train_loader`? And what type are they?